# How does ASM inform me about type annotations on casts and constructor calls

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, type-annotation

I'm analyzing the following two pieces of code use ASM (Api Version 5.0)

```
private Object x = new @TypeAnno3 Object();

private String myString = (@TypeAnno4 String) str;
```

And I'm trying to find the correct Visitor/Method to overwrite, to get notified about the two type annotations.

I managed to get all kinds of type annotations, but not these two ...

How do I do this?

Comment: I am not at my workstation to verify (thus comment rather than answer), but I strongly suspect MethodVisitor.visitInsnAnnotation method: http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitInsnAnnotation%28int,%20org.objectweb.asm.TypePath,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

Comment: @bkail Works, great. Make it an answer, please

Comment: @bkail I have another, very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29189158/66686 If you could help, it would be really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation information is available in the [MethodVisitor.visitInsnAnnotation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitInsnAnnotation%28int,%20org.objectweb.asm.TypePath,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) callback.