# What ASM Visitor Method gets called for type annotation on catch

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, type-annotation

I have the following code snippet, which I analyze with ASM

```
   try{
    } catch (@TypeAnno7 RuntimeException re){

    }
```

I can't find the right method that gets called for the Annotation. I thought [MethodVisitor.visitTryCatchAnnotation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitTryCatchAnnotation(int,%20org.objectweb.asm.TypePath,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) would do the trick, but it doesn't get called.

So: what is the correct method used? And for what kind of code does the method mentioned get called?

Comment: Is that literally the code? If your try body is empty, then the java compiler won't actually emit any code for the try/catch at all (check `javap -c`). Add some code to the try body to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Aaaargh, stupidity hurts. Wanna make that an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler does not generate any bytecode for a try/catch unless the try body contains some code (otherwise, the catch block could never actually run, so it's a form of dead code elimination), which you can verify using `javac -p`.  Add some code to the try body, and then the visitTryCatchAnnotation should be called.